# GridView Paging Issue with Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

Hi I have a `gridview` on which I am getting data from my attendance table, I am showing the data in `gridview` either by attendance date or by user biometric id or for all customer.

Now when I filter data by attendance date or biometric id and click on second page, it bounds only by date or biometric id.

```
protected void adetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{     
    adetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    adetails.DataBind();
    getdata();
    getdata2();
    getdata1();
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to specify the error/problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong databind should be done after getdata like

```
protected void adetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{     
    adetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    getdata();
    getdata2();
    getdata1();
    adetails.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, it's not working. My Question is if i binded Gridview by attendance date, and when i click on 2nd page of paging. Gridview is not keeping that i have binded data by attendance date. How can i solve this. Here we are filtering by attendance date and bio-metric id